# create android project and android-support-v7-appcompat is not included in lib(eclipse)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I fixed the problem. I used the workspace which was given by a python professor. I guess some sets do not match. After changing workspace, it works. Thank all you guys answer.

When i create a new android project, i ask eclipse create the activity for me. the code need to be imported v7, but there is not v7 in the lib. The error message shows up and stop the creating process. Anyone know how to fix it?（And i want to fix it in one time. i dont want it show up every time i create new project）(also if i cant fix it, eclipse cannot finish creating process,it means there are some unknown file have not be created before the error.this is the biggest problem)

```
[2014-11-26 23:39:54 - s] C:\EclipseWorkspaces\personal\s\res\values\styles.xml:7:  error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-11-26 23:39:54 - s] 
[2014-11-26 23:39:54 - s] C:\EclipseWorkspaces\personal\s\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-11-26 23:39:54 - s] 
[2014-11-26 23:39:54 - s] C:\EclipseWorkspaces\personal\s\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2014-11-26 23:39:54 - s] 
[2014-11-26 23:39:54 - s] C:\EclipseWorkspaces\personal\s\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-11-26 23:39:54 - s] 
[2014-11-26 23:39:54 - s] C:\EclipseWorkspaces\personal\s\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-11-26 23:39:54 - s] 
[2014-11-26 23:39:54 - s] C:\EclipseWorkspaces\personal\s\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2014-11-26 23:39:54 - s]
```

Comment: what is that error message??

Comment: sorry,just add. @sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a sample new Android project.please see the following screenshots hope this will help you

First I think you Error page will be look like this [image]

Second create new dummy  project

[image]

Third give a name to your dummy project i given as dummy and click next to proceed

[image]

Forth the project and support lib will be created

[image]

fifth Right click your main(error) project and select properties and then select Android
  [image]

Then click add lib in the library(is library).

[image]

Select apply to apply lib for the project 
   [image]

finally the error will be cleared 
     [image]

Comment: I fixed the problem. I used the workspace which was given by a python professor. I guess some sets do not match. After changing workspace, it works. Thank all you guys answer.